# How to round up a number to the nearest .5?

Tags: excel, decimal, rounding

How to round up a number to the nearest `.5` in excel?

For example round up number `77.2` to `77.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CEILING(number, significance)
```

- Number - The value you want to round.
- Significance -The multiple to which you want to round.

> Returns number rounded up, away from zero, to the nearest multiple of significance. For example, if you want to avoid using pennies in your prices and your product is priced at `$4.42`, use the formula `=CEILING(4.42,0.05)` to round prices up to the nearest nickel.

So, in your case:

```
CEILING(value, 0.5)
```

[More info on Microsoft support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CEILING-function-0a5cd7c8-0720-4f0a-bd2c-c943e510899f?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)